# Python 3 Пузырьковая сортировка в обе стороны

Tags: python-3.x, функции, пузырьковая-сортировка

Задание: Напишите функцию bubble(lst, a=False), которая принимает один обязательный аргумент - список из чисел, выполняет сортировку списка методом пузырька и возвращает получившийся список.

Аргумент desc задает порядок сортировки. Если он равен True, то функция сортирует по убыванию, если он равен False, то - по возрастанию.

По умолчанию функция сортирует список по возрастанию.

Запрещено использовать встроенные возможности языка для сортировки.

Нужна только функция ввод/вывод реализовывать не нужно

Подскажите, пжл, что не так с моим вариантом?

```
def bubble(lst, a=False):

    if a:
      for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        for j in range(len(lst)-i-1):
            if lst[j] > lst[j+1]:
                lst[j], lst[j+1] = lst[j+1], lst[j]
    elif not a:
      for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        for j in range(len(lst)-i-1):
            if lst[j] < lst[j+1]:
                lst[j], lst[j+1] = lst[j+1], lst[j]
  return lst
```

Comment: В одно случае lst[j] > lst[j+1] , в другом lst[j] < lst[j+1]

Answer (score -1):

```
def bubble(lst, desc = False):
    if ( not desc ):
        for i in range(len(lst)-1):
            for j in range(len(lst)-i-1):
                if lst[j] > lst[j+1]:
                    lst[j], lst[j+1] = lst[j+1], lst[j];
    else:
        for i in range(len(lst)-1):
            for j in range(len(lst)-i-1):
                if lst[j] < lst[j+1]:
                    lst[j], lst[j+1] = lst[j+1], lst[j];
    return lst;
```

Comment: Просьба минусующим - обосновывайте свои минусы.